# R function passing variable as string when first character is 0

Tags: r, function

I'm new to R and i'm trying to pass a 3 character as a function variable that begins with a zero, but it concatenates the zero. How do I pass it as a 3 characters beginning with zero?

```
  some_fun(007)
  
  some_fun(x){
    x
  }

  7
```

Comment: You need quotes '007'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, we need to pass a string.  If it is a numeric value with leading zeros, it will be dropped as the numeric don't allow it.  An option is to convert to `character` class

```
some_fun <- function(x) {
              sprintf('%03d', x)
 }
some_fun(7)
#[1] "007"
```

Comment: can this be done inside the function?

Comment: @alzchow updated the post with the function